# Is there a way to summarize the features of many time series?

Tags: time-series

I'm actually trying to detect characteristics of the time series for a very big region composed of many smaller subregions (in my case pixels). I don't know much about this, so the only way I can come up with is an averaged time series for the entire region, although I know this would definitely conceal many features by averaging.

I'm just wondering if there are any widely used techniques that can detect the common features of a suite of time series? like pattern recognition or time series classification?

Any ideas/suggestions are much appreciated!

Thanks!

Some extra explanations: I'm dealing with remote sensing images of several years with a time step of 7 days. So for each pixel, there is a time series associated, with values extracted from this pixel on different dates.So if I define a region consisting of many pixels, is there a way to detect or extract some common features charactering all or most of the time series of pixels within this region? Such as the shape of the time series, or a date around which there's an obvious increase in the values?

Comment: Could you detail your question a bit more and provide some context on what you want to achieve?

Comment: What do you mean by "time-series"? Are you speaking of a computer vision approach? Do you work with video or series of images or what? You question is very vague.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'm dealing with remote sensing images of several years with a time step of 7 days. So for each pixel, there is a time series associated, with values extracted from this pixel on different dates.So if I define a region consisting of many pixels, is there a way to detect or extract some common features charactering all or most of the time series of pixels within this region? Such as the shape of the time series, or a date around which there's an obvious increase in the values? Hope this makes my question less vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could compute the correlation matrix for the pixels. This would simply be:

```
corr = np.zeros((npix,npix))
for i in range(npix):
    for j in range(npix):
        corr(i,j) = sum(data(i,:)*data(j,:))/sqrt(sum(data(i,:)**2)*sum(data(j,:)**2))
```

If you want more information, you can compute this as a function of time, i.e. divide your time series into blocks (say minutes) and compute the correlation for each of them. Then you can see how the correlation changes over time.

If the correlation changes a lot, you may be more interested in the cross-power spectrum of the pixels. This is defined as

```
cpow(i,j,:) = (fft(data(i,:))*conj(fft(data(j,:)))
```

This will tell you how much pixel `i` and `j` tend to change together on various time-scales. For example, they could be moving in unison in time-scales of a second (1 Hz), but also have changes on a time-scale of, say, 10 seconds which are not correlated with each other.

It all depends on what you need, really.